# Vector projection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I am working on geometric graphing calculator, [something like this](https://beta.geogebra.org/graphing). If you select  "Segment" tool in Lines tool section and draw a line, then select "Perpendicular line" in Construct tool section, this would be what I need to do.

```
    len = 2500; // Length of perpendicular line
    vecA = {x1, y1}; // X, Y of mouse position
    vecB = {x2, y2}; // X, Y of vector B
    vecX = vecA.y - vecB.y;
    vecY = vecB.x - vecA.x;
    len = len / Math.sqrt(vecX * vecX + vecY * vecY);
    vecX *= len;
    vecY *= len;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.setLineDash([10, 2]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth.axis;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(vecA.x + vecX, vecA.y + vecY);
    ctx.lineTo(vecA.x - vecX, vecA.y - vecY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
```

The problem is that I am really bad at math and don't know how to convert Vector projection formula in JavaScript function. 
Now if I click initial line I get perpendicular lines but only if I move mouse X axis.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.